# PhpStorm function name suggestion with variables

Tags: tab-completion, phpstorm

How to make PHPStorm code completion to suggest function name with variables, not only it's   name?
For example, I have next function:

```
function sample1($understandable_variable_name1, &$some_Heavy_variable_name2) {
   // ...
}
```

Like, I am start entering `sampl`, it suggests `sample1`, but on `Enter` (or something another hotkey), it automatically put next: `sample1($understandable_variable_name1, $some_heavy_variable_name2)`

Comment: How would it know which arguments to use?

Comment: @gronostaj From declaration of function.